# How can I get top two tags?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Here are my tables's structures:

```
-- users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | Ali    |
+----+--------+

-- reputations
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | post_id     | user_id | score | reputation | date_time  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+ -- Suppose:
| 1  | 1           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1500489844 | -- out of last week
| 2  | 4           | 3       | -1    | -2         | 1500499815 | -- out of last week
| 3  | 2           | 3       | 1     | 5          | 1500584821 |
| 4  | 3           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1501389166 |
| 5  | 2           | 4       | 1     | 5          | 1501399142 |
| 6  | 2           | 1       | -1    | -2         | 1501399142 |
| 7  | 4           | 1       | 0     | 15         | 1501481186 |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
-- Note: the last row came from an accepted-answer, that's why its score is 0

-- post_tag
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2      |
| 1       | 4      |
| 2       | 2      |
| 3       | 1      |
| 3       | 4      |
| 4       | 3      |
+---------+--------+

-- tags
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | php    |
| 2  | html   |
| 3  | css    |
| 4  | mysql  |
+----+--------+

-- post_category
+---------+-------------+
| post_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | 2           |
| 2       | 3           |
| 3       | 1           |
| 4       | 2           |
| 5       | 1           |
| 6       | 2           |
| 7       | 1           |
+---------+-------------+
-- there is an unique index on post_id column. since each post can has only one category

-- categories
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | social     |
| 2  | technology |
| 3  | political  |
+----+------------+
```

Now I want to get list of users with their reputations, scores, top two tags in last week. How can I do that?

**Note1:**  *"top tow tags"* means the two tags that the user has earned more repo in them.

**Note2:** Each question has at least 1 tag.

---

Here is **the expected output:**

```
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+------------+
| id |  name  | score | reputation |   tags   |  category  |
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1  | Jack   | 0     | 18         | css,php  | technology |
| 3  | Ali    | 1     | 5          | html     | political  |
| 2  | Peter  | 0     | 0          | NULL     | NULL       |
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+------------+
-- Note: It's ordered by reputation, score columns
```

---

Here is **what I've tried:**

```
SELECT u.*,
      sum(r.score) as score,
      sum(r.reputation) as reputation
      /* WS_CONCAT(',', t.name) as tags */
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN reputation r ON r.user_id = u.id
/* I need more joins to get tags, I don't know how exactly */
WHERE r.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY reputation, score
```

As you can see, my query lacks the last column *(tags)*. Honestly, I don't know how I should manage such a thing. Do you know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a tricky job for MySQL (PostgreSQL and other DBs) can handle it much easier.

For the sake of clarity, I've changed your `tag.name` to `tag.tag` and `user.name` to `user.user_name`, so that there's less risk of confusing the `name`s. Note also that your data contains a user `4`. I've called him James.

Let's do it one step at a time.

### Step 1

First, let's get your expected output *minus* the tags:

```
SELECT 
     u.id, 
     u.user_name,
     coalesce(sum(r.score), 0) as score,
     coalesce(sum(r.reputation), 0) as reputation
FROM 
    users u
    LEFT JOIN reputations r 
        ON r.user_id = u.id 
           AND r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
GROUP BY 
    u.id, u.user_name
ORDER BY 
    reputation DESC, score DESC ;
```

```
id | user_name | score | reputation
-: | :-------- | ----: | ---------:
 1 | Jack      |     0 |         18
 4 | James     |     1 |          5
 2 | Peter     |     0 |          0
 3 | Ali       |     0 |          0
```

NOTE: the condition `r.date_time > 1500584821` *must* be part of your `JOIN ON` condition. If it is in the `where` clause, your `LEFT JOIN` becomes just an `INNER JOIN`, and you will lose users with no reputation.

### Step 2

Now we make another query that returns, for every user_id, the list of tags and its corresponding reputation:

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.user_name, t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN reputations r 
        ON r.user_id = u.id 
            AND r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.user_name, t.tag 
ORDER BY
    u.id, tag_reputation DESC;
```

```
id | user_name | tag   | tag_reputation
-: | :-------- | :---- | -------------:
 1 | Jack      | css   |             15
 1 | Jack      | php   |              5
 1 | Jack      | mysql |              5
 1 | Jack      | html  |             -2
 4 | James     | html  |              5
```

### Step 3

We `LEFT JOIN` the two together (after a smallish simplification of the second, to ignore user names there), `ON user_id` *and* `GROUP BY user_id, user_name, score, reputation`

```
SELECT
    q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation, 
    substring_index(group_concat(q2.tag  ORDER BY q2.tag_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS top_two_tags
FROM
    (SELECT 
        u.id AS user_Id, 
        u.user_name,
        coalesce(sum(r.score), 0) as score,
        coalesce(sum(r.reputation), 0) as reputation
    FROM 
        users u
        LEFT JOIN reputations r 
            ON    r.user_id = u.id 
              AND r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY 
        u.id, u.user_name
    ) AS q1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        r.user_id AS user_id, t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation
    FROM
        reputations r 
        JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
    WHERE
        r.date_time > 1500584821 /* unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) */
    GROUP BY
        user_id, t.tag
    ) AS q2
    ON q2.user_id = q1.user_id 
GROUP BY
    q1.user_id, q1.user_name, q1.score, q1.reputation
ORDER BY
    q1.reputation DESC, q1.score DESC ;
```

```
user_id | user_name | score | reputation | top_two_tags
------: | :-------- | ----: | ---------: | :-----------
      1 | Jack      |     0 |         18 | css,mysql   
      4 | James     |     1 |          5 | html        
      2 | Peter     |     0 |          0 | null        
      3 | Ali       |     0 |          0 | null
```

Note that `group_concat(q2.tag  ORDER BY q2.tag_reputation DESC SEPARATOR ',')` does return *all* tags associated with the user. We cut to two by means of `substring_index(string,separator,number)`.

You can find all the settings, and queries at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e171298affc2b90d99e0024be780fc76)*

---

**Side note (ties when ranking)**: for user `Jack`, the `php` and `mysql` tags have the same `tag_reputation`. I.e.: there's a tie between second and third. In that case, and without a *second* criterion for *sorting* the tags, both `css,mysql` and `css,php` are acceptable answers for the "top two" tags.